# Extract Data from 1 column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

What's the best and simplest way to look extract the fruit_name and fruit_colour from a dataframe of one messy column? Each fruit is listed in order but there can be irrelevant detail in between

```
df

    col
1   fruit_name
2   apple
3   fruit_colour
4   green
5   fruit_number
6   10
7   no information
...
10  fruit_name
11  banana
12  irrelevant_nonsense
13  fruit_colour
14  yellow
14  genearl_fin
15  fruit_name
16  pear
17  fruit_name
...
```

Expected Output

```
    fruit_name   fruit_colour   
0   apple         green
1   banana        yellow
2   pear          NaN
```

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible sample data? Is it safe to assume the format will always follow a format of one key then one value?

Comment: ```df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['fruit_name', 'apple', 'fruit_colour', 'green','fruit_number',10,'no information','fruit_name','banana','irrelevant_nonsense','fruit_colour','yellow','genearl_fin','fruit_name'], })``` Ideally a generalisable solution please, so if there's no colour listed then the fruit_colour would be NaN

Comment: In that case do we know what keys to expect? Do we only want to parse out fruit_name and fruit_color?

Comment: yep only data under fruit_name and fruit_colour and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

A funky way is to use `.shift`

```py
…

pd.DataFrame({"fruit_name": df[df.shift(1).eq('fruit_name').values].iloc[:, 0].to_list(),
"fruit_colour":df[df.shift(1).eq('fruit_colour').values].iloc[:,0].to_list()})


## Output
#   fruit_name  fruit_colour
# 0 apple   green
# 1 banana  yellow
```

I don’t think it is effective. You will also have issues if there are uneven values ;)

Comment: This doesn't work if the fruit has no colour listed unfortunately

Comment: Can you share example of data with that and what you would like to get if no colour?

Comment: I have updated the df in the question

Comment: It is doable. We need to add logic to add NaN if the shifted element is not what we expect. Example to check if it contains `_`, then `NaN`. But again, it’s beginning to look like the tasks could be rethinked. Perhaps check if you can control the pipeline prior to this step.